# How to get maximum TCP Receive/Send window in MAC OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, tcp, sysctl

How to get maximum TCP Receive/Send window  in MAC OS X?

There are two ctl in Linux.
/proc/sys/net/core/rmem_max - Maximum TCP Receive Window  (NET_CORE_RMEM_MAX)
/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max - Maximum TCP Send Window     (NET_CORE_WMEM_MAX)

but i couldn't find how to get these parameters in mac os.

Does anybody know?

I have found the following ctls in MAC OS X:
net.inet.tcp.recvspace, net.inet.tcp.sendspace, kern.ipc.maxsockbuf

It seems that recvspace+sendspace can't be greater than maxsockbuf. 
I have read about it here:
http://www.macgeekery.com/tips/configuration/mac_os_x_network_tuning_guide_revisited

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure whether these are the correct ones, but try `sysctl -n net.inet.tcp.recvspace` and `sysctl -n net.inet.tcp.sendspace`. You can set them with `sysctl -w` (see `man sysctl`).

Comment: These ctls (net.inet.tcp.recvspace, net.inet.tcp.sendspace) gave me current tcp buffers sizes for send and receive. I need to know maximum value to recvspace and sendspace.  The only idea is: kern.ipc.maxsockbuf

Comment: IPC is shorthand for InterProcessCommunication, so I doubt this is it.

Comment: Actually socket api is one of the ipc tool. I am not sure about kern.ipc.maxsockbuf. I have read it in the article mentioned above. I should run some tests.

Answer (score 1):

As OP mentioned: `recvspace+sendspace < maxsockbuf`

`maxsockbuf` is limited by `kern.ipc.nmbclusters`, `nmbclusters*2KB/16=maxsockbuf`

```
sysctl -a | egrep nmbcl\|maxsockb
kern.ipc.maxsockbuf: 8388608
kern.ipc.nmbclusters: 65536
```

To increase `maxsockbuf`, tell the system to use more than the
default `mbufclusters` via the ncl boot arg: (you need to disable SIP before edit boot-args)

```
nvram boot-args="ncl=131072"
shutdown -r now
```

quote from [here](https://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-kernel/2012/Apr/msg00043.html)