# What is the Default value of SO_SNDBUFF and SO_RCVBUFF set in the OS X system?

Tags: objective-c

```
int32_t rcvBuf = 400 * 1024;
    setsockopt(socketFD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &rcvBuf, 4);f

int32_t checkRcvBuf = 0;
unsigned int checkRcvBufLen = sizeof(checkRcvBuf);
getsockopt(socketFD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &checkRcvBuf, &checkRcvBufLen);

int32_t sndBuf = 400 * 1024;
setsockopt(socketFD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &sndBuf, 4);

int32_t checkSndBuf = 0;
unsigned int checkSndBufLen = sizeof(checkSndBuf);
getsockopt(socketFD, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &checkSndBuf, &checkSndBufLen);
```

Comment: can i set the value throgh this code?? am i doing right or wrong...

Comment: what is the Default value of SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF in OS X???

Comment: i read in AppleDoc https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setsockopt.2.html The system places an absolute limit on these
     values. what's the limit??????

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get maximum TCP Receive/Send window in MAC OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508798/how-to-get-maximum-tcp-receive-send-window-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Access the root of your shell (terminal)...
2. run the `/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default` file in to your shell
3. as you reach your file run this command `sysctl -a`
4. then run the next command like `sysctl -a | grep -i space`
5. then you get the default size of `SNDBUF` and `RCVBUF` of your OS.

Comment: This isn't very clear.  "run the ... in to your shell" is execute a process, or `cat` the file?  "as you reach your file" means what, what does "reach" mean in this context?  Is "space" literal text in the grep command?

Answer (score 5):

On MAC OSX you can see all `sysctl` variables via:

```
$ sysctl -a
```

If you grep those for the prefix `net.inet.tcp`

```
$ sysctl -a|grep net.inet.tcp
```

You can see all related variables.  You are looking for these two:

```
net.inet.tcp.sendspace: 131072
net.inet.tcp.recvspace: 131072
```

Showing are the current values on my system.

These can also be set via `sysctl` and use `man sysctl` for more information on doing so, an example of setting one of these values:

```
$ sudo sysctl net.inet.tcp.sendspace=131072
```

These must be set with root privileges and likely if `sysctl` can set the value, then C/C++ code can likely do the same if it can access the OS kernel functions for doing so (likely must be run as `root`).

**See also:**

`sysctl` source:

- https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-597.1.1/sysctl.tproj/sysctl.c
- http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/sys/sysctl.h

Tuning MAC OSX kernel configuration:

- http://www.macfreek.nl/memory/Kernel_Configuration

Kernel functions in Objective-C:

- https://developer.apple.com/reference/kernel/2011260-kernel_functions?language=objc

And the fact that people are at least reading these parameters from Swift means it is possible from Objective-C as well:

- http://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/03/08/swift-wrapper-for-sysctl.html

Related `sysctl` functions available for coding:

- http://opensource.apple.com//source/xnu/xnu-1456.1.26/bsd/kern/kern_newsysctl.c